# Make search NOT case sensitive on my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using this gem: http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/ I have successfully setup search on my app. Here is the scope that is used.

```
scope :search_by_name, ->(name){ where(name: name) }
```

Lets say there is a name of 'Jonathon' and you search for 'jon' I would like for it to bring that result up. Also, as it stands now if you search for 'jonathon' (change J to j) it doesn't show the result. You have to have it exactly as the entry.

Comment: Assuming your DB is case sensitive (like postgresql), if you look at the docs in the linked site (http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/pages/active_record_scope_patterns.html#search)  you will see how they are showing how to search by the use of `LOWER` and downcasing the search terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stay portable between databases, consider changing your scope to a named method and use AREL matches.

```
def search_by_name(name)
  where(arel_table[:name].matches(name))
end
```

Though maybe a scope could work:

```
scope :search_by_name, ->(name){ where(arel_table[:name].matches(name)) }
```

Since a named scope is the same as a method, especially when you pass it a lambda variable, there is no disadvantage of it being a method instead of a scope.

You may need to prepend or append a `%` (or both) to the name argument for it to look for anything containing the argument (instead of only exact case-insensitive matches.   So perhaps...

```
def search_by_name(name)
  where(arel_table[:name].matches('%' + name + '%'))
end
```

Comment: That fixed my case sensitive issue with the new scope. Where should I be placing the 'def'? The controller of the item being filtered? Sorry in advance for my newbish ways :)

Comment: No worries.  It should just go in the same model that you had the scope in.  You can make the call from within the controller.  You should avoid putting this method in the controller because you generally want thin controllers (and so fat models) but more because things about the model should stay with the model.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, if the modified scope version worked, you don't need the `def` method.  The method form was an alternate, not in addition.

Comment: this got me the result I was looking for
`scope :search_by_name, ->(name){ where(arel_table[:name].matches('%' + name + '%')) }`